# Problems with mutated vowels and Option Clash

Tags: package-options

My Problem is that i have wrong packages for Mac, i think.
I obviously cannot write ö,ü,ä and somehow the package "`\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}`" does not help.

My packages are as follows:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   packages.tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   provides used packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%% Language %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{babel}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{isGerman}}%
{ %% German
    \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % w√§hle Neudeutsch als Erstsprache, Englisch als     Zweitsprache (f√ºr Trennregeln)
        \selectlanguage{ngerman}
    }%
    { %% English
        \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % w√§hle English als Erstsprache, Neudeutsch als      Zweitsprache (f√ºr Trennregeln)
    \selectlanguage{english}
}


\makeatletter
%\makeatother

%%%% General
\usepackage{fixltx2e}               % Patches for LaTeX
\usepackage{etex}                           % An extended version of TeX, from the NTS project
    \reserveinserts{28}
\usepackage{morewrites}             % Always room for a new write stream
\usepackage{etoolbox}                   % Tool-box for LaTeX programmers using e-TeX
\usepackage{environ}                    % A new interface for environments in LaTeX
\usepackage{xparse}                     % A generic document command parser
\usepackage{xstring}                    % String manipulation for (La)TeX


%%%% paper geometry
\usepackage{geometry}                       % Flexible and complete interface to document dimensions
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper,
    bindingoffset=1.0cm, % gutter
    inner=2.0cm, % inside margin
    outer=3.0cm, % outside margin
    vmargin=2.5cm, % top and bottom margins
    marginparsep=0.5cm,
    marginparwidth=2.0cm,
}
\usepackage{mparhack}                   % Work around a LaTeX bug in marginpars
\usepackage{calc}                           % Simple arithmetic in LaTeX commands

%%%% input & text, appearance encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}        % Accept different input encodings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Standard package for selecting font encodings
\usepackage{lmodern}                    % alternative Computer Modern-fonts for computer screens
\usepackage{textcomp}                   % LaTeX support for the Text Companion fonts
\usepackage{xspace}                     % Define commands that appear not to eat spaces


%%%% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Enhanced support for graphics
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%% PGF % TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}                           % pgf-tikz
\usepackage{hf-tikz}                    % A simple way to highlight formulas and formula parts
\usepackage{pgfplots}                   % Create normal/logarithmic plots in two and three dimensions
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}      % Loads, rounds, formats and postprocesses numerical tables
%\usepackage{pgfkeyx}                   % Extended and more robust version of pgfkeys
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest,
    table/col sep=semicolon,        % use semicolon as column seperator in input data (CSV)
    width=\textwidth                        % make tikzpictures as big as possible
}
\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
    calc,
    cd,
    arrows
}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{isGerman}}%
{ %% German
    \pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        set decimal separator={,},
        set thousands separator={\,},
        min exponent for 1000 sep=4,
    }
}%
{ %% English
    \pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        set decimal separator={.},
        set thousands separator={\,},
        min exponent for 1000 sep=4,
    }
}


% use pgf librarys
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/}
\tikzexternalize[%
    shell escape=-enable-write18,   % swich externalization on/off
    %up to date check=md5, % default
    %mode=list and make, % only with makefile
    %force remake=1 % remake all pictures
]


%%%% Math typesetting
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % AMS mathematical facilities for LaTeX
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   % TeX fonts from the American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % pre-defined math symbols
\usepackage{amsthm}                     % Typesetting theorems (AMS style)

\usepackage{mathtools}              % Mathematical tools to use with amsmath
\mathtoolsset{
    showonlyrefs=true,
    showmanualtags=true
}

%\usepackage{breqn}                     % Automatic line breaking of displayed equations

\usepackage{bbm}                            % "Blackboard-style" cm fonts
\usepackage{bm}                             % Access bold symbols in maths mode
\usepackage{upgreek}                    % Upright Greek letters

\usepackage{siunitx}                    % A comprehensive (SI) units package
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    per-mode = symbol,
}

%%%% enhance functionality
%\usepackage{enumerate}             % Enumerate with redefinable labels
\usepackage[
    shortlabels% compatibility with \usepackage{enumerate}, which is now obsolete
]{enumitem}                                     % Control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
\setlist[enumerate]{
    align=left, %parleft
    leftmargin=*,
    %rightmargin=0pt,
    listparindent=\parindent,
    %labelwidth=0pt,
    %labelsep=0pt,
    itemindent=0pt%
}

\usepackage{float}                      % Improved interface for floating objects
\usepackage{lineno}                     % Line numbers on paragraphs
\usepackage{pdfpages}                   % Include PDF documents in LaTeX
\usepackage{caption}                    % Customising captions in floating environments
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}   % A range of footnote options
\usepackage{subcaption}             % Support for sub-captions
\usepackage{relsize}                    % Set the font size relative to the current font size
\usepackage{chngcntr}               % Change the resetting of counters
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{aliascnt}                   % Alias counters


%%%% Table
\usepackage{rotating}                   % Rotation tools, including rotated full-page floats
\usepackage{multirow}                   % Create tabular cells spanning multiple rows
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % Publication quality tables in LATEX
%\usepackage{array}                     % Extending the array and tabular environments
\usepackage{colortbl}                   % Add colour to LATEX tables

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}  % set row spacing in tables


%%%% Miscelangelous

%\usepackage{siunitx}                   % A comprehensive (SI) units package
%\sisetup{
    %output-decimal-marker = {,},
    %per-mode = symbol,
%}

\usepackage{listings}               % Quellcode einbinden und formatieren
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Code}    % default: List of Listings
%\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{darkviolett}{rgb}{.5,0,.5}
\newlength\charlength
\setlength{\charlength}{\widthof{\texttt{X}}}
\newlength\listingnumberwidth
\setlength\listingnumberwidth{\widthof{00} + 1em}       % \widthof{00} means 2 digit numbers
\lstset{
    language=R,                         % oder  C++, Pascal, {[77]Fortran}, ...
    numbers=left,                   % Position der Zeilennummerierung
    firstnumber=auto,               % Erste  Zeilennummer
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,     % Textgr√∂√üe  des Standardtexts
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},    % Formattierung Schl√ºsselw√∂rter
    commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{gray},       % Formattierung Kommentar
    stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{purple},             % Formattierung Strings
    %keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
    %commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
    %stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny,              % Textgr√∂√üe der Zeilennummern
    stepnumber=1,                   % Angezeigte Zeilennummern
    numbersep=1em,                  % Abstand zw. Zeilennummern und Code
    aboveskip=\bigskipamount,                 % Abstand oberhalb des Codes
    belowskip=\bigskipamount,                 % Abstand unterhalb des Codes
    captionpos=b,                   % Position der √úberschrift
    linewidth=\textwidth,               % TODO \textwidth-2em
    xleftmargin=\listingnumberwidth,                                % Linke Einr√ºckung
        xrightmargin=4pt,                               % Rechte Einr√ºckung
    frame=single,                   % Rahmentyp
    breaklines=true,                % Umbruch langer Zeilen
        breakatwhitespace=true,                 % If true, it allows line breaks only at white space
    showstringspaces=false,         % Spezielles Zeichen f√ºr Leerzeichen
        breakindent=8\charlength,               % is the indention of the second, third, . . . line of broken lines.
        tabsize=2
}

%%%% Index
%\usepackage{multind}                   % Multiple indexes in LaTeX documents
%\makeindex{a}
\usepackage{makeidx}                    % Standard LaTeX package for creating indexes
\makeindex

\let\origindex\index
%\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{\marginpar{#1}\origindex{#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{#1\origindex{#1}}


%%%% Nomenclature (List of Symbols and Abbreviations)
\usepackage[
    %norefpage,     % default
    refpage,
    norefeq,        % default
    %refeq
]{nomencl}                  % Produce lists of symbols as in nomenclature
\makenomenclature


%%%% Acronym
%\usepackage{acronym}                   % Expand acronyms at least once


%%%% Bibliography
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex8, %bibtex, %biber, %bibtex8,
    bibencoding=auto,
    sorting=nyvt,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
  doi=false,
    eprint=true
]{biblatex}                                     % Bibliographies in LaTeX using BibTeX for sorting only
\addbibresource{./bib/thesis.bib}

%\usepackage{doi}                           % Create correct hyperlinks for DOI numbers

\usepackage{csquotes}                   % Context sensitive quotation facilities



%%%% Creative Commons
\usepackage[
    scale=1
]{ccicons}                                      % LaTeX support for Creative Commons icons
\usepackage{cclicenses}             % Typeset Creative Commons licence logos


%%%% PDF/A PDF/X support
%\usepackage{pdfx}                      % PDF/X-1a and PDF/A-1b support for pdfTEX
%\input{./licence/pdfa-supp}
%\includexmp{./licence/cc-by-nc-sa_Diss}


%%%% PDF
%\input{./latex/pdf.tex}
%\usepackage[
    %pdfborder={0 0 0},
    %colorlinks=true
%]{hyperref}                                    % Extensive support for hypertext in LaTeX

%% show backref in bibliography
%\RequirePackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
%\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  
%\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    %%\newline
    %\ifcase #1 
        %Not cited.
    %\or
        %Cited on page #2.
    %\else
        %Cited on pages #2.
    %\fi
%}


%%%% Glossary (load after hyperref)
%\usepackage[
    %%xindy,
    %toc,
    %acronym,
    %nopostdot,
    %%counter=page
%]{glossaries}                                  % Create glossaries and lists of acronyms
%%\usepackage{glossary-longragged}
%%\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} % remove dot at end of each description
%
%\newglossary{index}{gls}{glo}{\glossaryname}
%
%\makeglossaries


%%%% End %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother

\endinput
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx!

Comment: `\usepackage[...]{inputenc}` will help but you need to declare the encoding that your file uses. this maybe utf8 rather than the legacy apple encoding. You need to determine that (as we can not tell from the website, the data is always utf8 by the time it gets here)

Comment: I use TexShop, but i don't know what MAC-encoding is actually. But thanks for your answers.
Where i can look what encoding my file uses?

Comment: @edeka Open the Preferences for TeXShop, the default encoding will be self evident in the “Source” panel.